# Ruby on Rails 3 Limited Multi-table query and Array Typecasting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, multiple-tables

I'm trying to show only 5 reviews from a specific category as opposed to 5 reviews of any category.  I have posted the later which was working for comparison purposes.

The reviews have a category id index, which I then use to look up the Category name and compare that name to the Category Name of the reviews I want.  I then store the 5 reviews I extract in an array (is this the most efficient way?).  The reviews and categories are two separate tables.

Currently I'm getting the error "can't convert Review into Array".  I'm guessing this is a typecasting issue?   I don't want the Review to become an array.  I want the result to be equivalent to the old code where @review holds 5 reviews.
I'm not sure if I'm approaching this problem correctly.

Current Code

```
   def home
    @review = []
    idx = 1
    Review.find_each do |review|
      break if idx == 5
      @category = Category.find(review.category_id).category_name
      if @category == "Something"
        @review += review and idx+=1
      end
    end
  end
```

Old Code

```
def home
  @review = Review.find(:all, :limit => 5)
end
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is that `review` contains a Review object and you are trying to concatenate it to an array, but array concatenation only works between arrays.

i.e. `[1,2,3]+[4]` gives `[1,2,3,4]`, but `[1,2,3]+4` gives an error.

You can use `<<` or `push` instead, or you can wrap the review object in an array:

```
@reviews << review
```

or

```
@reviews.push review
```

or

```
@reviews += [review]
```

...respectively.

---

Alternatively, I'm sure there's a more idiomatic way to do what you are trying to do.

I'm not sure of all the rails3 stuff yet, but something like:

```
Category.where(:category_name => "Something").first.reviews.limit(5)
```

This assumes an association between Review and Category:

In the Review model:

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :category
  ...
end
```

In the Category model:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :reviews
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.  It is now working.

As for you more idiomatic way, I agree with you but your solution does not work as Category/Review does not have a parent/child relationship.  Review just has a foreign key of the category

Comment: The relationship doesn't have to be parent/child and only a foreign key is required for you to set up an association (assuming there is no other undue restriction on doing so.) The above use case is exactly the sort of reason to define an association.

Comment: The error I'm getting is "undefined method `reviews' for #<Category:0x53e0ff8>"  Can you explain further?  I don't understand how this could work.  The Category does not have a review_id foreign key so how can reviews be called on Category?  Only Reviews has a foreign key of Category.

Comment: You need to define the association in the model. Review having a foreign key of Category is essentially the minimum required for a one-to-many association from Review to Category (ie: one Review can have/be in many Categorys). I will edit my answer to include the details.

Comment: Oops, got the association the wrong way around in my last comment, should read: a one-to-many association from Category to Review (ie: one Category can have many Reviews)